# Update MySQL data with exist variable

Tags: mysql

in my my-sql user data, there are two columns, which are u_id and u_name.

I would like to update u_name as u_id if there is no value.

```
UPDATE T_USER_ACCOUNT SET `u_name`=`u_id` WHERE `u_name` = 'NULL'
```

I ran this query but it affected 0 row.

what caused the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assign (`=`) `null` to a column when you want to compare with `NULL` values. The correct way is:

```
UPDATE T_USER_ACCOUNT SET `u_name`=`u_id` WHERE `u_name` IS NULL
```

in your query,

```
UPDATE T_USER_ACCOUNT SET `u_name`=`u_id` WHERE `u_name` = 'NULL'
```

you are searching for `u_name` which has a **String** or **VARCHAR** value of `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

When comparing to `NULL` use `IS NULL`:

```
WHERE u_name IS NULL
```

Notice that I have changed two things:

- `NULL` is not in quotes.
- Use `IS` instead of `=` when comparing to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE T_USER_ACCOUNT SET `u_name`=`u_id` WHERE `u_name` IS NULL
```

You should use Is NULL for checking the null values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IS NULL`:

```
UPDATE T_USER_ACCOUNT SET `u_name`=`u_id` WHERE `u_name` IS NULL
```